# How do i store a session array inside jquery variable? Laravel / Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, session

I'm trying to store a session array inside a jquery variable.

My code:

```
<script>
@if(session()->has('zoektermen'))
    var zoektermen = '{{ session()->get('zoektermen') }}';
    console.log(zoektermen);
@endif
</script>
```

Putting in session inside controller:

```
if(isset($_GET['searchquery'])) {
    $searchquery = $_GET['searchquery'];
}

if(session()->has('zoektermen')) {
    session()->forget('zoektermen');
    session()->put('zoektermen', $searchquery);
} else {
    session()->put('zoektermen', $searchquery);
}
```

But i'm getting an error because {{ }} expects a string and not an array.

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

What is the correct way to store the array from the session into a JS array?

Comment: Try with other blade `{!! !!}` and see.

Comment: You can not use php array to JS. You have to convert to JSON and then you can use there

Comment: @PandhiBhaumik Same error Array to string conversion

Comment: Then you likely did not do it correctly ... encoding any data object as JSON _will_ give you a string value.

Comment: Your code is not sufficient to solve this issue, paste the whole or relevant code from which the errors causes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use php `json_encode` and decode in JS to get PHP array in JavaScript

```
<script>
@if(session()->has('zoektermen'))
    var zoektermen_json = "{{ json_encode(session()->get('zoektermen')) }}";
    var zoektermen = JSON.parse(zoektermen_json);
    console.log(zoektermen);
@endif
</script>
```

Comment: I'm getting this error :SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: @JordyGroote : what after replacing `{{ ... }}` to `{!!  ...  !!}`  ?

Answer (score 3):

Do like this

```
<script>
@if(session()->has('zoektermen'))
    var zoektermen = '{{json_encode(session()->get("zoektermen"))}}';
     zoektermen= $.parseJSON(zoektermen);
    console.log(zoektermen);
@endif
</script>
```

I thing it will help you.

Comment: escape quotes or use double quotes arounds here `'{{json_encode(session()->get('zoektermen'))}}'`